# Bootstrap 4 dropdown issue inside navbar fixed-top

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I spent the last day trying to figure why a dropdown inside a navbar didn't work when the viewport change.

If you look at that generic example via phone (or developer tools) and rotate the orientation to landscape, you will see that the links on the dropdown are unreachable.

I was trying to add scroll to .dropdown with overflow: scroll!important without no success. I also try to position it on top with position fixed and it didn't work.

My desired result would be that if the menu expand over the view, you can scroll the screen (or even the dropdown menu itself) to see the other links.

**Note that when I remove the class "fixed-top" from the nav it all work as expected so I guess it is something with that.**

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body style="padding-top: 70px;">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Dropdown
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>          
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>          
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <main>
            <p>Example</p>
            <p>Example</p>
            <p>Example</p>
            <p>Example</p>
            <p>Example</p>
            <p>Example</p>
            <p>Example</p>
            <p>Example</p>
            <p>Example</p>
            <p>Example</p>
            <p>Example</p>
            <p>Example</p>
            <p>Example</p>
            <p>Example</p>
            <p>Example</p>
            <p>Example</p>
            <p>Example</p>
            <p>Example</p>
            <p>Example</p>
            <p>Example</p>
            <p>Example</p>
            <p>Example</p>
            <p>Example</p>
            <p>Example</p>
            <p>Example</p>
            <p>Example</p>
            <p>Example</p>
            <p>Example</p>
            <p>Example</p>
            <p>Example</p>
            <p>Example</p>
            <p>Example</p>
            <p>Example</p>
        </main>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var fixed = document.getElementById('fixed');

fixed.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

}, false);
```

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  max-height: 70vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 990px) {
  .navbar.fixed-top {
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 100vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.5/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav id="#fixed" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Dropdown
                        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<main>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
</main>
```

Set a maximum height for the navbar with css:

```
@media (max-width: 990px){
  .navbar.fixed-top{
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 100vh;
  }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've already try that. It doesn’t work because although you can scroll to see the other links, you have to scroll till the end of the document. And when you close the nav, you are in the bottom of the page. I can't understand how and where bootstrap ignores the custom css (like overflow, height etc), for the dropdown in a nav bar fixed-top.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your problem. If you want the navbar scrollbar to have priority over th body scrollbar, you'll need some js.

Comment: I'm willing to take any solution.. your update still not fixing the issue. Thanks again for your kindness. I opened an issue on gitub project also.

Comment: The custom css seems to be working on chrome. https://codepen.io/zoiloreyes/pen/KrMdMr which web browser are you using?

Comment: ok... it semi works. Although the dropdown now (finally) have scroll, i still can't see all the links on landscape mode... I'll try to fix it via css @media. Thanks again.